# Password Protecting an Excel Workbook from Viewing in SharePoint

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, password-protection

I am trying to password protect an Excel workbook, so that only people with the password can view. I am trying to protect the ENTIRE workbook from VIEWING, without hiding the sheet and protecting it that way. I need something that will work to prevent anyone in my organization from viewing the file that do not have the password.

I used the steps File --> Info --> Protect Workbook --> Encrypt with Password. This works well when I open the file with the Excel App, however, this file is in SharePoint and I'm noticing if it's opened in the browser, you can see behind the password protected box to one of the sheets.. I've attached a picture for reference (please ignore my poor white-out skills).

[image]

I've tried using VBA Password Protection but once I save and exit, it does not prompt a password input and doesn't retain the settings I change. My organization prevents changing the Link Settings to "Anyone with the Link" on SharePoint so that solution doesn't work either.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: How about hiding all the sheets, and having VBA unhide them all when the workbook opens? The VBA won't run unless the password is given. You would also need to have VBA automatically hide the sheets before closing.